# There is not a GO button in the menu bar

Tags: macos

Any idea how to add a GO button to my menu bar to the MAC PRO?
Menu bar I have contains:  Safari  File  Edit  View  History  Bookmarks Window  Help

NO "GO" Bar

Comment: 'Go' is a Finder menu, not Safari. Click the desktop then look again.

Answer (score 1):

Start Finder: then the menu bar reads:
Finder File Edit View GO Window Help.
It is a Finder menu not Safari menu that has GO.